# li as tabs, combine hover(or mouseenter and mouseleave) and click

Tags: jquery

I have problem with tabs (using `li`). I dont know how to solve this situation: by click tab(tab link) not show tab content, but if i hover tab again to show tab content. (just first click not show the tab content)

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul id="tabstest">
        <li id="first_tab" style="width:200px; height:40px;"><a href="#tab1" class="active tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\auto.php';"><strong>Auto</strong></a></li>
        <li style="width:180px; height:40px; line-height: 12px;"><a href="#tab2" class="tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\automk.php';"><strong><br>Automk</strong></a></li>
        <li style="width:120px; height:40px;"><a href="#tab3" class="tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\info.php';"><strong>Info</strong></a></li>
        <li style="width:180px; height:40px; line-height: 12px;"><a href="#tab4" class="tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\tteleko.php';"><strong><br>Teleko</strong></a></li>
        <li style="width:120px; height:40px; line-height: 12px;"><a href="#tab5" class="tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\pamet.php';"><strong><br>Pamet</strong></a></li>
        <li id="last_tab" style="width:100px; height:40px; line-height: 12px;"><a href="#tab6" class="tab_link" onclick="window.location.href = '\rracun.php';"s><strong><br>Računari</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabcontents" >
        <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
        <img src="/images/baner22.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="Slideshow Image 2" title="Slideshow Image 2" style="float:left; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;"/>
        <p style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;">tab1 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
        <p>tab2 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent" >
        <p>tab3 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabcontent">
        <img src="images/baner22.jpg" width="947" alt="Slideshow Image 2" title="Slideshow Image 2" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tabcontent">
        <img src="/images/baner32.jpg" width="947" alt="Slideshow Image 2" title="Slideshow Image 2" />
        </div>
        <div id="tab6" class="tabcontent">
        <img src="/images/banner35.jpg" width="947" alt="Slideshow Image 2" title="Slideshow Image 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
  $("#tabstest li").click(function() { 

          ????

});


 $("#tabstest li").hover(function () {

$("#tabstest li").removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass("active");

  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

          }, function () {

$("#tabstest li").removeClass('active');

  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    $(selected_tab).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  On first click it wont do anything.  But after first click it will show the data.

```
var clickCount = 0;
$("#tabstest li").click(function() { 
     if (clickCount > 1) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
     }
     clickCount++;
});


 $("#tabstest li").hover(function () {

$("#tabstest li").removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass("active");

  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

          }, function () {

$("#tabstest li").removeClass('active');

  var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    $(selected_tab).hide();
});
```

Comment: I have tried with this code, but again it doesnt work... Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Example: I mouseeneter to 2nd tab - I see tab content. I click on 2nd tab, page is opened with the same tabs, but I dont see 2nd tab content. If I mouseleave and enter in some other tab I will se content of tab. If I back mouse enter in 2nd tab, 2nd tab content will show regardless I click 2nd to open page.

Comment: I find other solution (jsfiddle.net/x2975 just put click funtion the same code like mouseleave). It works with "clasic" li, but if I put li as link using <a>, click function is behave very strange - some click hide tab content, but some not hide, and I dont know of what depends like there is no rule... How can we fix it? Do you have any idea?    I dont know how to replay with code... :-/ I am new user here... Sorry